# Problema Hibernate validaciones

Tags: java, validación, hibernate

gente tengo problemas con las validaciones de Hibernate (uso la version 7.0 )  Sencillamente pese a que hago exactamente lo mismo que en el tutorial, no me toma como error dejar los input en blanco o ponerle menos de 2 letras (uso @NotNull y @Size) . Lo que sucede es que en el IF del metodo procesarFormulario de la clase ControladorAlumno aparentemente siempre da false el boolean hasErrors() aunque deje los campos vacíos. Leí en un comentario que este error podría desaparecer si se usa una version de Hibernate mas vieja. Pero no entiendo el motivo si eso es verdad.

Clase ControladorAlumno:

```
package es.pildoras.spring.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import jakarta.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/alumno")

public class ControladorAlumno {

    @RequestMapping("/mostrarFormulario")
public String mostrarFormulariox(Model modelo) {
        Persona persona = new Persona();
        modelo.addAttribute("persona", persona);        
        return "Formulario";
    }
    

    @RequestMapping("/procesarFormulario") //recordar que la barra va xq termina siendo una URL aunque si se la llama desde un link en JSP no hace falta ponerla
    public String procesarFormulario(@Valid @ModelAttribute("persona") Persona persona, 
             BindingResult resultadovalidacion) {
        
        if(resultadovalidacion.hasErrors()) {
            
            return "Formulario";
        } else {
            
            return "ResultadoFormulario";
            
        }                   
    }
    }
```

Vista:

```
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>  

<!DOCTYPE html>

    

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1> a </h1>

<form:form action="procesarFormulario" modelAttribute="persona"> 

Nombre : <form:input path="nombre"/>
<form:errors path="nombre" style="color:red"/>

<br>
Apellido: <form:input path= "apellido" />
<br>
Edad: <form:input path = "edad" />

 <input type="submit" value="enviar"/>
 
 </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Clase a validar

```
package es.pildoras.spring.mvc;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;

public class Persona {

@NotNull
@Size (min=2, message="campo requeridooo")
private String nombre;

private String apellido;

private int edad ;



public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}
public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}
public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}
public int getEdad() {
    return edad;
}
public void setEdad(int edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que debiste de agregar las dependencias de forma manual porque `Spring` aun no ha integrado las ultimas librerías de validación, este un problema que se vera en muchos proyectos al estar obligado la Eclipse Foundation a migrar los paquetes de `javax` a `jakarta`, la solución seria utilizar la dependencia de spring boot que te agrega la validación para estar seguro de las dependencias:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

De esta forma tendrías las anotaciones como `@Valid` `@NotNull` del paquete `javax` no `jakarta` que son las soportadas actualmente.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta. Dónde debo agregar ese bloque de código? soy realmente principiante con Spring y jamás había visto esto de agregar dependencias de forma manual. No he visto Spring Boot todavía

Comment: @favio Edita tu pregunta y agrega el POM o la lista de librerías que estas utilizando para ver que dependencias necesitas agregar y quitar.